# Create a singleton object of ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, singleton, uistoryboard

After calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"popvc2id" sender:self];` my `ViewController2` will get initialize through `awakeFromNib` method.

I want to create a `singleton object of ViewController2` using `storyboard`

How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you need a VC to be a singleton ?

Comment: Its my requirment

Comment: Yes, but why? VC's are not designed to be singletons and this sounds like abuse of the singleton paradigm. There's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have to prevent the VC to initialize again, I want just one instance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is good practice.
But if you want one instance from your view controller you can give a tag for view in your view controller, or using storyboard id and then you can access it using accessor method.
This access method init the controller for you and save it in dictionary and the next time you call it, it will return the saved instance for you.

Like that:

```
+(yourviewcontrollerclassname *)getViewController{
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    yourviewcontrollerclassname * vc;
    if (![_viewControllers containsObject:@"vc-identifier"]){
       vc = (yourviewcontrollerclassname *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc-identifier"];
       [_viewControllers setObject:vc forKey:@"vc-identifier"];
    }else{
       vc = (yourviewcontrollerclassname *)[_viewController objectForKey:@"vc-identifier"];
    }
    return vc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `SyncViewController` is my singleton ViewController. I need to show the current Sync progress so i don't need to init ViewController each time when user want to see the sync progress.

in `SyncViewController.m`

```
static SyncViewController *sharedInstance;
```

Following is the method to get sharedInstance of ViewController.

```
+ (SyncViewController *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        sharedInstance=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SyncViewController"];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Open Singleton ViewController from another View Controller :

```
    SyncViewController *syncVC=[SyncViewController sharedInstance];
    [self presentViewController:syncVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```